# Best way to flip a UIImage in a CALayer who's origin is not at (0,0)

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

Greetings... I come in peace, shoot to kill...

I have a container of type UIView (A Grid) and add many sublayers to the layer of the UIView (CALayers representing cells within the grid).

Within the Cell, I render many UIImages at different locations using CGContextDrawImage. I am well aware of the need to Translate and Scale, but the scaling (flipping) is with reference to the superviews (Grid) co-ordiantes and the origin of the Cell CALayer is not (0,0).

Therefore my rendering is all over the shop (mostly off screen). What is the best way to handle the translating and scaling when the UIImage is not at (0,0). Is there an established design pattern I should be using.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand as originally written, you should really post a code snippet that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by just manually offsetting the translation by double the y origin.